# Change input value and add cursor at the end of input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I change input value and don't want to blur and focus again on input to make the cursor at the end tried other ways but didn't work

```
thisEl.val("0"+thisEl.val()+"/");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt focus() method to bring focus to an element. Details can be found here: [mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus). 
Example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oao0kw36/

```
thisEl.val("0"+thisEl.val()+"/").focus();
```

Comment: The thing is that I change the value when user has focus and they type in.

Comment: Found the problem. Cause I was using mask plugin I couldn't make it. Now is okay.

Comment: Ok, that's great !